# How to mock a class in C# unit testing project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class I want to moq :

```
    public class ODriver
    {
        public int DriverId { get; set; }      

        public virtual bool CanDrive()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

She is used like this in the method I want to test :

```
    var driver = new ODriver();

    // Must be false except in the unit test
    var canDrive = driver.CanDrive();
```

I mock the method like this in my unit test :

```
  var driverMoq = new Mock<ODriver>();
  driverMoq.Setup(d => d.CanDrive()).Returns(true);
```

When the test is runned, the result of the CanDrive method returns false. What do I have to do in order to have the mocked class used ?

Thank you all !

Comment: Sounds like you don't use `driverMoq.Object` for the unit test and instead use `new ODriver()`

Comment: 404 is right. Just made a try and driverMoq.Object.CanDrive() returns true.

Comment: Please, share your test and `driverMoq` usage

Comment: Yes I don't use the driverMoq.Object, I use the new ODriver() in the method I want to test, this method doesn't know the moq and I don't want my production code to use a Moq. Maybe mocking a class is not what I expected.
I thought mocking a class will "replace" all calls to the class with my moqs methods. It's not how it works ?

Comment: No. When you create a mock you create a fake with the behavior you want (in that case returns true instead of false). But that behavior is only available if you use the mock itself. 
And you should never user a mock in production code of course, only in tests.

Comment: If you want to change the behavior of your production code for a test, you should consider to create your mock and inject it (see dependency injection).

Comment: @Pierre-Luc no, you create a mock object and pass it instead of real instance

Comment: Yes Acord I am agree with you, the depency injection pattern will return the moq object. I thought it will be automagical the moqs, my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is :
I adapted the code of the method I tested and added the ODriver object as parameter.

Thank you for your help, I didn't know how it works.

PierreLuc